# How to compile an installation with the makefile?

Tags: makefile, compilation

I'm installing a program called nauty using cygwin. It starts asking to run using "configure", so far everything has been fine. However, it asks to perform a "make" to compile the installation. I don't know what to write to perform the compilation.

The "makefile" file contains the following code:

```
# initial stub makefile for nauty

# Use configure to create the real makefile

SHELL = /bin/sh

all: nauty gtools;

nauty : dreadnaut dreadnautB ;

gtools : copyg listg labelg dretog amtog geng complg shortg showg NRswitchg \
      addedgeg deledgeg countg pickg genrang newedgeg catg genbg directg ;

dreadnaut:message;
dreadnautB:message;
copyg:message;
listg:message;
labelg:message;
dretog:message;
amtog:message;
geng:message;
complg:message;
shortg:message;
showg:message;
NRswitchg:message;
addedgeg:message;
deledgeg: message;
count: message;
pick: message;
genrang:message;
newedgeg:message;
catg:message;
genbg:message;
directg:message;

message: cat config.txt
```

I hope you can help me on what I should write to perform the compilation and finalize the installation.

Comment: Did you type `make` at your shell prompt?  What happened?

Comment: The following message appears: "-bash: make: command not found".  I wrote: "gcc -c make" and it didn't compile either.

Comment: You can't compile make unless you download the source code for it first.  You can't compile a new program out of thin air.  You need to install an already-built version of make on your system.  You say you're using cygwin, so you need to get the cygwin version of make and install it.